# how use a application-dev.yml from Jhipster on local path

Tags: java, jhipster

Im trying to use the file application.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml that jhipster has in the proyect, but i dont want to use this file from the proyect i want to use those file from a local path. for example C://path

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Comment: i from chile, and my english its not so good.... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely a spring-boot mechanism not specific to JHipster.
Look at [spring-boot doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) for all possibilities.
In your case, you could use:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:///C:/path/application-dev.yml
```

but the simplest is to put your yaml file in same directory as your jar file, this is what is often used in production.